# php namespace all files in directory

Tags: php

> Namespaces are declared using the namespace keyword. A file containing a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before any other code - with one exception: the declare keyword.

*php manual on namespaces definition*

Is it possible to give an entire directory a namespace without the necessity to declare the namespace at the beginning of each individual file?

Answer (score 5):

The direct answer is NO. You can declare multiple namespace for a single file but a single namespace cannot be declared to multiple file with a single line of statement. You have to do it in each files.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible for all your classes within a directory to use the same namespace, but you still have to declare the namespace inside each class file, for example if you had a directory structure:

```
/App/Core/
```

All classes in that folder could have the same namespace:

FileA.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Core;
class FileA {}
```

FileB.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Core;
class FileB {}
```

Depending on the code editor you use, you may be able to automate the process of updating all files so you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

No. Ideally, files in same directory should 'obey' to one namespace. But ...

> The namespace hierarchy will normally mirror the directory hierarchy
>   where the class files are located, but this is not a strict
>   requirement. You could, for example, have several class flles with
>   different namespaces in the same directory.